# TypeScript error when accessing property of object literal

Tags: typescript, object-literal

I'm a beginner in TypeScript.
I had a bit problem when accessing data of an `Object`.

```
let content:Array<string> = ["I", "am", "a", "beginner"]
let data:Object = {a: "foo", b: content}
console.log(data.a);
console.log(data['b']);
console.log(data.b);
```

This code will have an error in line 5. (no error in JavaScript)
Please, explain it to me.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: No reason to feel sorry - See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the explicit declaration of `data` to be of `Object` so that TypeScript will infer the type, i.e. change it to something like this

```
let content:Array<string> = ["I", "am", "a", "beginner"]
let data = {a: "foo", b: content}
console.log(data.a);
console.log(data['b']);
console.log(data.b);
```

The reason for your error in your initial code is because you are telling the TypeScript compiler that `data` is of type `Object` or any derived class from that - as the type `Object` has no properties `a` or `b` this results in an error.

Please note that removing the explicit type annotation is not the same as using `any` as suggested by [AD.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/users/693272/ad-net) as in this case TypeScript still has all the type information available - just inferred (see the screenshot of Visual Studio Code), whereas by using `any` you are telling the TypeScript compiler that the variable could refer to anything which results in no type checking.

[image]

Comment: You might mention that the reason the initial assignment works is that TS ignores **extra** properties.

Comment: #torazaburo I am starting learning Typescript. I had a problem with my data in my project. But now I understand.

Comment: That's a good point about not using `any`, I haven't used TS in a while :(

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `data:any`, at least you will not get any error. If you want intellisense, you'll need to create a `type/interface` for `data`, e.g.

```
interface myData{
    a:string;
    b:Array<String>
}
data:myData
```

then you can have intellisense.